# javascript to parse csv excel file

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, csv

I am trying to parse a CSV file I made in Excel. I want to use it to update my Google map. This Google map is in a mobile app that I am developing with Eclipse for Android.

Honestly, I am not sure how to write the JavaScript. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I would be happy to credit your work.

I just want some JavaScript to run when the user hits a button that does the following:

1. Locates users current location (I have already done this part!)
2. Locate nearby locations as entered in the .CSV excel file by parsing the .CSV
3. Display a small link inside every locations notification bubble that says "Navigate" that when the user clicks it, opens google maps app and starts navigating the user to that location from the users current location (Geolocation).

This is the ONLY part I need to finish this application. So once again, any help at all will be greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I've been round and round with this problem. The CSV format is not made for easy parsing and even with complicated RegEx it is difficult to parse.

Honestly, the best thing to do is import it into an FormSite or PHPMyAdmin, then re-export the document with a custom separator that is easier to parse than ",".  I often use "%%" as the field delimiter and everything works like a charm.

Comment: hmmm...What would you suggest a good way of doing this other than using a .CSV file? What other methods are their? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example, please?

Comment: Some applications (not MS excel, not Google Docs, yes FormSite, yes PHPMyAdmin), offer to export a CSV with a custom field delimiter. You are still using CSV, but are using %% as the thing that gets placed between the fields.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if this will help but see http://www.randomactsofsentience.com/2012/04/csv-handling-in-javascript.html if it helps...

Additional:
On top of the solution linked to above (my preference) I also used a shed load of stacked regular expressions to token a CSV but it's not as easy to modify for custom error states...

Looks heavy but still only takes milliseconds:

```
function csvSplit(csv){
  csv = csv.replace(/\r\n/g,'\n')
  var rows = csv.split("\n");
  for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
    var row = rows[i];
    rows[i] = new Array();
    row = row.replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
    row = row.replace(/\\\\/g, "&#92;");
    row = row.replace(/\\"/g, "&quot;");
    row = row.replace(/\\'/g, "&#39;");
    row = row.replace(/\\,/g, "&#44;");
    row = row.replace(/@/g, "&#64;");
    row = row.replace(/\?/g, "&#63;");
    row = row.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, "@$1\?");
    while (row.match(/@([^\?]*),([^\?]*)\?/)){
      row = row.replace(/@([^\?]*),([^\?]*)\?/g, "@$1&#44;$2?");
    }
    row = row.replace(/[\?@]/g, "");
    row = row.replace(/\'([^\']*)\'/g, "@$1\?");
    while (row.match(/@([^\?]*),([^\?]*)\?/)){
      row = row.replace(/@([^\?]*),([^\?]*)\?/g, "@$1&#44;$2?");
    }
    row = row.replace(/[\?@]/g, "");
    row = row.split(",")
    for (var j=0; j<row.length; j++){
      col = row[j];
      col = col.replace(/&#63;/g, "\?");
      col = col.replace(/&#64;/g, "@");
      col = col.replace(/&#44;/g, ",");
      col = col.replace(/&#39;/g, '\'');
      col = col.replace(/&quot;/g, '\"');
      col = col.replace(/&#92;/g, '\\');
      col = col.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
      row[j]=col;
    }
    rows[i] = row;
  }
  return rows;
}
```

Comment: These are nice, but unfortunately neither of these solutions work for CSV's that have line breaks in a cell (perfectly valid for excel).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem which is why I had to come up with this answer, I found on npm a something called [masala parser](https://github.com/masala/masala-parser) which is indeed a parser combinator. However it didn't run on browsers yet, which is why I am using this fork, the code remains unchanged. Please read it's documentation to understand the Parser-side of the code.

```js
import ('https://cdn.statically.io/gh/kreijstal-contributions/masala-parser/Kreijstal-patch-1/src/lib/index.js').then(({
  C,
  N,
  F,
  Streams
}) => {


  var CSV = (delimeter, eol) => {
 //parses anything beween a string converts "" into "
    var innerstring = F.try(C.string('""').returns("\"")).or(C.notChar("\"")).rep().map(a => a.value.join(''));
    //allow a string or any token except line delimeter or tabulator delimeter
    var attempth = F.try(C.char('"').drop().then(innerstring).then(C.char('"').drop())).or(C.charNotIn(eol[0] + delimeter))
    //this is merely just a CSV header entry or the last value of a CSV line (newlines not allowed)
    var wordh = attempth.optrep().map(a => (a.value.join('')));
    //This parses the whole header
    var header = wordh.then(C.char(delimeter).drop().then(wordh).optrep()).map(x => {
      x.header = x.value;
      return x
    })
    //allow a string or any token except a tabulator delimeter, the reason why we allow newlines is because we already know how many columns there is, so if there is a newline, it is part of the value.
    var attempt = F.try(C.char('"').drop().then(innerstring.opt().map(a=>(a.value.__MASALA_EMPTY__?{value:""}:a))).then(C.char('"').drop())).or(C.notChar(delimeter))
    //this is merely just a CSV entry
    var word = attempt.optrep().map(a => (a.value[0]?.value??a.value[0]));
    //This parses a CSV "line" it will skip newlines if they're enclosed with doublequotation marks
    var line = i => C.string(eol).drop().then(word.then(C.char(delimeter).drop().then(word).occurrence(i - 1).then(C.char(delimeter).drop().then(wordh)))).map(a => a.value);
    return header.flatMap(a => line(a.header.length - 1).rep().map(b => {
      b.header = a.header;
      return b
    }))
  };

  var m = {
    'tab': '\t',
    "comma": ",",
    "space": " ",
    "semicolon": ";"
  }

  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var val = document.getElementById('csv').value;
    var parsedCSV = CSV(m[document.getElementById('delimeter').value], '\n').parse(Streams.ofString(val)).value;
    console.log(parsedCSV);

  })
})
```

```html
Type some csv<br>
<textarea id="csv"></textarea>
<label for="delimeter">Choose a delimeter:</label>

<select name="delimeter" id="delimeter">
  <option value="comma">,</option>
  <option value="tab">\t</option>
  <option value="space"> </option>
  <option value="semicolon">;</option>
</select>
<button id="button">parse</button>
```

I would suggest stripping the newlines and the end of the file. Because it might get confused.

Answer (score -2):

This appears to work. You may want to translate the Japanese, but it is very straight-forward to use:
http://code.google.com/p/csvdatajs/